# Shader looks weird in Unity

Tags: cycles-render-engine, unity

I imported my model from Blender into Unity and I noticed that the colors were off in the Unity scene. This is even before I add the UV map to my object. As you can see in the picture below, there is some discoloration near the duck's armpit area (and on the other side as well). I thought it could be a lighting issue, but the discoloration is still there with direct light. I also don't think it is a reflection issue. My blender model looks fine so I'm not sure where to start looking for a solution. In front of a duck I put a cube which has no lighting issues. I also changed all the Standard Shade settings of the duck to match the cube, but am getting the same result.  I am at a loss :/

EDIT:

Here is the link to download the blender file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51537

[image]

Comment: can you upload your model somewhere?  That would help people to diagnose the issue.  It's likely something with normals.

Comment: thanks, I will check that. I pasted a link to the blender file

Comment: ok, the problem is that the mesh is deforming terribly around the armpits.  You can see it inside of blender how the mesh gets all deformed as the arms animate.  With that tangled of a mesh you can't expect it to be shaded properly.

Comment: I removed all the weight paint from the arm pit area but am still seeing the dark spot on my model in Unity. Any suggestions for getting rid of the deformation? Or maybe I can make my scene bright/dark enough that it's not as noticeable.